# humanize in django/python, how to translate

Tags: django

i only need a quick way to translate days in italian in django.
Using humanize it works properly but obviously always in english

```
<h1 class="">{{ h.datainserimento|date:"d M Y"  }} | {{ h.nomegiorno }}</h1>

def nomegiorno(self):
   pio = self.datainserimento.strftime("%A")
   return pio
```

to:

```
<h1 class="">21 May 2014 | Wednesday</h1>
```

thanks!

Comment: I need translate too and can't find answers.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use hard-coded, for a test, `translation.activate(language)` just before sending it:

```
def nomegiorno(self):
   old = translation.get_language()
   print('old', old)
   translation.activate('it')
   pio = self.datainserimento.strftime("%A")
   translation.activate(old)
   return pio
```

And tell me what you have, this should help anyway